# Problem with nested lambda expressions - unable to add to outer list vairable

Tags: java, file, search, lambda

I'm trying to search a string in the parallel stream of files. There is a compilation error at (outputLines =) this step. I'm unable to figure out the problem. Please help. I need to keep the code for inputFiles.parallelStream() and then for each I need to read the file line by line and then search for the string. I'm unable to do so. Please advise. Thank you.

```
    public List<String> searchForText(List<Path> inputFiles, String SEARCH_TOKEN) {
        List<String> outputLines = new ArrayList<>();
        inputFiles.parallelStream().forEach(path -> {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
                outputLines = lines.filter(a -> a.trim().contains(SEARCH_TOKEN)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return outputLines;
    }
```

I tried multiple ways to add the line to outputLines but as it is called inside the lambda expression it is forcing me to be final. When there are nested lambda expressions how to add to the list from outer lambda expression from inner lambda expression. Please advise.

Comment: Did you mean to use `outputLines.addAll` instead of assigning to `outputLines` (though that's probably not thread safe)? This seems like you should just `flatMap` instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

Java lambdas only support references to final variables, refer to [this article on to why it is that way](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables).

In your case you could simply do

```java
    public List<String> searchForText(List<Path> inputFiles, String SEARCH_TOKEN) {
        final List<String> outputLines = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        inputFiles.parallelStream().forEach(path -> {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
                outputLines.clear();
                outputLines.addAll(lines.filter(a -> a.trim().contains(SEARCH_TOKEN)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        return outputLines;
    }
```

Or if you want to stick with the variable reassignment you could also just use a normal for each loop, which of course wouldn't be parallel anymore, like so:

```java
    public List<String> searchForText(List<Path> inputFiles, String SEARCH_TOKEN) {
        List<String> outputLines = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Path path : inputFiles) {
           try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
                outputLines = lines.filter(a -> a.trim().contains(SEARCH_TOKEN)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return outputLines;
    }
```